# Can I create an ack file type based on a filename, not extension?

Tags: ack

I would like to include files with a specific name -- not an extension -- in my `ack` search. Is this possible with ack?

If I use the `-G` option, this would exclude all other file types. (So I can't put it in my `.ackrc` file.)

I tried to use `--type-set mytype=filename.txt` but this only works for extensions, so this would search for files including the pattern `.filename.txt`, thus not find `filename.txt`. (That's also what the `ack --help types` shows: `--mytype .filename.txt`, not `--mytype filename.txt`.)

Someone any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`man ack` says that the files to be searched in can be given through standard input.
So this should work:

`find . -name filename.txt | ack PATTERN -`

Unfortunately, it doesn't. It gives `ack: Ignoring 1 argument on the command-line while acting as a filter.`, which apparently is a [bug in ack](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/158). When this bug [will be fixed](https://github.com/petdance/ack/issues/106), we should be able to use

`find . -name filename.txt | ack --nofilter PATTERN -`

Comment: In the mean time, just use xargs:
`find . -name filename.txt | xargs ack PATTERN -`

Answer (score 6):

You also do it like if you're using `zsh`:

`ack 'Pattern' **/filename.txt`

Comment: In my case, this doesn't check all the files `filename.txt` in the subtree, only some of them.

Comment: This seems to depend on the shell you are using. For bash you can go on searching like this: `*/filename.txt, */*/filename.txt,...`

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking is "can I make a filetype that ack recognizes based on a filename", and the answer is "No, not in ack 1.x, but you can in ack 2.0".  ack 2.0 is in alpha release, and we hope to have a beta by Christmas.

As @Christian pointed out above, you can specify the given filename on the command line, but that bypasses filetype checking entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late reply, but could you simply specify the filename when you run ack?

```
ack 'My Text' filename.txt
```

Comment: -> `ack filename.txt: No such file or directory` unless there is a `filename.txt` in the current directory, but that would still ignore all the other files with this name in the subdirectories.